# How to use AWS S3 JavaScript SDK with Lightning Web Components as 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, aws, amazon-s3

I am trying to initialize the AWS constant in my LWC component but always it is undefined.

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import AWS_SDK from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/awssdk';

export default class AwsFileExplorer extends LightningElement {    
    albumBucketName = BUCKET__NAME;
    accessKeyId = ACCESS__KEY;
    secretAccessKey = SECRET__KEY;
    region = 'us-east-2';
    s3;    


    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.awsSdkInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.awsSdkInitialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, AWS_SDK),            
        ])        
            .then(() => {
                this.awsSdkInitialized();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }

    awsSdkInitialized() {        
        const AWS = AWS;
        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId : this.accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey : this.secretAccessKey
        });

        AWS.config.region = this.region;

        this.s3 = new AWS.S3({
            apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
            params: {Bucket: this.albumBucketName}
        });

        console.log(this.accessKeyId);
        console.log(this.s3);

    }

    listS3Objects() {
        this.s3.listObjects(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Success", data);
            }
          });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a third party library function gets attached to a window object in salesforce when referenced from static resource.

The key is notice how i use window variable.

```
const AWS = window.AWS;
```

The below should work

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import AWS_SDK from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/awssdk';

export default class ParentCmp extends LightningElement {

 albumBucketName = 'BUCKET__NAME';
 accessKeyId = 'ACCESS__KEY';
 secretAccessKey = 'SECRET__KEY';
 region = 'us-east-2';
 s3;

 awsSdkInitialized = false;

 renderedCallback() {
    if (this.awsSdkInitialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.awsSdkInitialized = true;

    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, AWS_SDK),
    ])
        .then(() => {
            this.awsSdkInitialize();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

awsSdkInitialize() {
    const AWS = window.AWS;
    console.log(AWS);
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId : this.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey : this.secretAccessKey
    });

    AWS.config.region = this.region;

    this.s3 = new AWS.S3({
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        params: {Bucket: this.albumBucketName}
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way earlier as well, but still it is undefined for me.
The same way if I try with some other 3rd party library then it works, but in this situation it doesn't works.

Comment: It was not undefined for me .It did print all the functions when I did window.AWS

Comment: Also what is coming undefined ?

Comment: I came across this topic in search for the correct js file that must be uploaded as Static Resource. For others with the same quest: we find that file here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/tree/master/dist . We need aws-sdk.min.js